# Рефакторинг Python: задать произвольное число индексов для выборки

Tags: python, index, dict, рефакторинг

Имею две функции:

```
def matrix_list_company(size, index):
    with open(file1) as f1:
        data = json.load(f1)
    comp = [line[index] for line in data]
    return random.sample(comp, int(size))

def matrix_list_fio(size, f, i, o)
    with open(file2) as f2:
        data = json.load(f2)
    comp = [[line[f], line[i], line[o]] for line in data]
    return random.sample(comp, int(size))

matrix_list_company(2, 'company_name')
matrix_list_fio(2, 'first', 'name', 'middle')
```

Каким образом можно оптимизировать этот пример, оставив универсальную функцию matrix_list, которая будет принимать индекс различной длины, и доставать по нему данные из файла?

Comment: `def matrix_list(size, *index)`?

Comment: И `comp = [[line[x] for x in index] for line in data]`

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных и то что хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Да, совет @andreymal помог - теперь вместо двух почти одинаковых функций можно делать вот такие вызовы универсальной matrix_list:

`    namelist = matrix_list(m, 'lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename')`
`    tinlist = matrix_list(n, 'tin')`